# Serverpod Authentication errors

Tags: postgresql, flutter, authentication, serverpod

I just started using serverpod and I'm trying to find an easier to detect if there is a wrong password enter, email in use so on... so far the documentation and google search's only show how to use the sign in and register methods but don't show error handling.

So far i'm using postgres statements to check if an error occurred how ever that is still very limited in what I can check

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.